# How to align password box according to the remaining textboxes in an order

Tags: javascript, html, css

Actually i was validating password and used hover to show the required prerequisites in a box and it was working when i created password textbox in jsfiddle but when i wanted to incorporate that password textbox in signup page the entire structure of the page has changed and i couldn't figure out why it has changed. I am posting the code below and jsfiddle.

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById("psw");
var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
var number = document.getElementById("number");
var length = document.getElementById("length");

// When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
myInput.onfocus = function() {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
myInput.onblur = function() {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
}

// When the user starts to type something inside the password field
myInput.onkeyup = function() {
  // Validate lowercase letters
  var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {  
    letter.classList.remove("invalid");
    letter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    letter.classList.remove("valid");
    letter.classList.add("invalid");
  }
  
  // Validate capital letters
  var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {  
    capital.classList.remove("invalid");
    capital.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    capital.classList.remove("valid");
    capital.classList.add("invalid");
  }

  // Validate numbers
  var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {  
    number.classList.remove("invalid");
    number.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    number.classList.remove("valid");
    number.classList.add("invalid");
  }
  
  // Validate length
  if(myInput.value.length >= 8) {
    length.classList.remove("invalid");
    length.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    length.classList.remove("valid");
    length.classList.add("invalid");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
margin:0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center; 
}

/* Style the tab */
.frame {
  height: 575px;
  width: 430px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(
    rgba(35,43,85,0.75),
    rgba(35,43,85,0.95));
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-top: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  
}
.nav {
 padding-top:40px;
}

li {
 
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  
}

.btn {
  cursor : pointer;
  color: rgb(255,255,255);
  padding: 10px;
}
   
.form-signin {
 padding-left:30px;
 padding-top:50px;
 padding-right:30px;
}

label {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: rgb(255,255,255);
  display: block;
}

.form-styling {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  color :rgb(255,255,255);
}

.btn-animate {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
  padding-top: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  background-color: rgba(16,89,255, 1);
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.check
{
 font-size : 20px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgb(255,255,255);
  padding-left :15px;
 
}

.forgot
{
 color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:400px;
 cursor:pointer;
 text-decoration:underline;
 padding-left : 165px;
 
}

:focus {
 outline: none;
}
.toggle {
 background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
 border-radius: 25px;
}

span{
    background:#F8F8F8;
    border: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
    color: #717171;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    
    top: -190px;
    left:190px;
    display:none;
    padding:0 10px;
    
}


span:after{
    
    position:relative;
    
    
    
    border-bottom:1px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-right:1px solid #dfdfdf;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    
    
}
p{
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
}

p:hover span{
   display:block; 
}

.valid {
    color: green;
}
.valid:before {
    position: relative;
    left : -10px;
    content: "✔";
}

/* Add a red text color and an "x" when the requirements are wrong */
.invalid {
    color: red;
}

.invalid:before {
    position: relative;
    left:-10px;
    content: "✖";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  
  <div class="frame">
  <div class="nav">
  <ul>
  
  <li><a class="btn">Sign up </a></li>
  </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="signup-show">
    <form class="form-signin" action="/SignIn_Up/addadmin" method="post" name="form">
    <label for="username">FullName</label>
          <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="fullName" required/>
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="email" required/>
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <p><input class="form-styling" type="password" id="psw" name="password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" required><span id="letter" class="invalid">A Lowercase Letter</span><span id="capital" class="invalid">A Capital  Letter</span><span id="number" class="invalid">A <b>Number</b></span><span id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>8 Characters</b></span></p>
          <label for="password">Confirm Password</label>
          <input class="form-styling" id="confirmPassword" type="password" name="confirmPassword" min="6" max="15" required/>
         
                    <input class="btn-animate" type="Submit" value="Submit"/>

            <br/>
     </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please do not post executable versions of your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Just post your code in a "code snippet", right here in your question (as I've done for you).

Comment: Okay Thank you and i will keep in mind when i will post a question next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are positioning your elements seems to be the culprit.

Here is a simple solution for you. This will wrap your password requirements in a span with a unique id and style that as well as the spans inside accordingly to get the required behavior Here is that:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}


/* Style the tab */

.frame {
  height: 575px;
  width: 430px;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(35, 43, 85, 0.75), rgba(35, 43, 85, 0.95));
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-top: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.nav {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

li {
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 10px;
}

.form-signin {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

label {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
}

.form-styling {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.btn-animate {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  padding-top: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(16, 89, 255, 1);
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.check {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.forgot {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding-left: 165px;
}

:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.toggle {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 25px;
}

span {
  background: #F8F8F8;
  border: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
  color: #717171;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  display: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

#reqs{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  position:absolute;
  top: 165px;  
  left:225px;
  
}

span:after {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  border-right: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

p {
  position: relavive;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin:0;
}

p:hover span {
  display: block;
}

.valid {
  color: green;
}

.valid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  content: "✔";
}


/* Add a red text color and an "x" when the requirements are wrong */

.invalid {
  color: red;
}

.invalid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  content: "✖";
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>

      <li><a class="btn">Sign up </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="signup-show">
    <form class="form-signin" action="/SignIn_Up/addadmin" method="post" name="form">
      <label for="username">FullName</label>
      <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="fullName" required/>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="email" required/>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <p><input class="form-styling" type="password" id="psw" name="password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" required>
        <span id="reqs"><span id="letter" class="invalid">A Lowercase Letter</span><span id="capital" class="invalid">A Capital  Letter</span><span id="number" class="invalid">A <b>Number</b></span><span id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>8 Characters</b></span></span>
      </p>
      <label for="password">Confirm Password</label>
      <input class="form-styling" id="confirmPassword" type="password" name="confirmPassword" min="6" max="15" required/>

      <input class="btn-animate" type="Submit" value="Submit" />

      <br/>
    </form>
  </div>
```

I have had best luck with placing the requirements directly below the input in question and letting the page and other elements flow around them. This keeps the structure of your page nice and clean and it won't send your values off the page. I'll show you what you need to change to do this below.

First off, you will want to change `position` of the `p` tag to `relative` (it is currently set to `absolute`. If you want to see the input and the button below your spans you will just need to change the `height` of the `.frame` class to `auto` instead of the fixed height of `575px`. This still looks weird as you have placed the requirement to the left and up of the input in question. As I have said I think it will look cleanest if you just let them flow with the page and go under the input in question (this will look better on mobile too. To do this you can just get rid of your `top` and `left` styles from your `span` tag.

Here's a code snippet with the following changes.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}


/* Style the tab */

.frame {
  height: auto;
  width: 430px;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(35, 43, 85, 0.75), rgba(35, 43, 85, 0.95));
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-top: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.nav {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

li {
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 10px;
}

.form-signin {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

label {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
}

.form-styling {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.btn-animate {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  padding-top: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(16, 89, 255, 1);
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.check {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.forgot {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding-left: 165px;
}

:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.toggle {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 25px;
}

span {
  background: #F8F8F8;
  border: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
  color: #717171;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  display: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

span:after {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  border-right: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

p {
  position: relavive;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p:hover span {
  display: block;
}

.valid {
  color: green;
}

.valid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  content: "✔";
}


/* Add a red text color and an "x" when the requirements are wrong */

.invalid {
  color: red;
}

.invalid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  content: "✖";
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>

      <li><a class="btn">Sign up </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="signup-show">
    <form class="form-signin" action="/SignIn_Up/addadmin" method="post" name="form">
      <label for="username">FullName</label>
      <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="fullName" required/>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="email" required/>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <p><input class="form-styling" type="password" id="psw" name="password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" required>
        <span id="letter" class="invalid">A Lowercase Letter</span><span id="capital" class="invalid">A Capital  Letter</span><span id="number" class="invalid">A <b>Number</b></span><span id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>8 Characters</b></span></p>
      <label for="password">Confirm Password</label>
      <input class="form-styling" id="confirmPassword" type="password" name="confirmPassword" min="6" max="15" required/>

      <input class="btn-animate" type="Submit" value="Submit" />

      <br/>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but when i hover on password span is coming up and then confirm password and submit. And also when i hover password,frame is getting shaking or something like that which looks weird actually

Comment: what do you mean "i hover on password span is coming up and then confirm password and submit" If you mean the password requirements are showing before confirm password and submit, that is how I have it styled. Would you like it to be above the password input?

Comment: And I'm not sure what you mean by "frame is getting shaking or something". I'm not getting any kind of shutter or shaking when I hover. Just an expansion of the height to include the password requirements.

Comment: If you would like to stick with your original design plan you can achieve this by adding a span with an id around your password requirements and styling that. Again I don't recommend this as it's bad for responsiveness. Here is a JS Bin with those applied. Let me know if that's what you want and I'll update my answer accordingly. http://jsbin.com/siquvukoke/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Yes yes that's what i want. I have been looking for that quite sometime

Comment: The one you posted in JSBin looks pretty good and simple and make it interesting as well

Comment: @FIFAoneterahertz, OK. Post has been updated with the desired code snippet listed first. Please consider accepting if this is indeed the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: One question for me which is this

Comment: Is there anyway that pop-up comes at the end of the textbox . i mean like this  http://jsfiddle.net/v8xUL/1/

Comment: Sure.. Here is a [JSBin link](http://jsbin.com/herugaroso/edit?html,css,output) with that. Hope this helps. I recomend cleaning up the unwanted styles and such but the tool tip seems to be what your asking for.

Comment: Thank You. You have done more than what i expected and i asked for. Keep up your good work :)